# Yandex MapKit 3

Tags: yandexmapkit

Ошибка при компиляции:
1. Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process D:\apps\app\app\build\intermediates\transforms\profilers-transform\debug\58.jar
2. Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.
3. Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -2147483648

Как происходит:
1. Добавляю в build.gradle (classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2') implementation 'com.yandex.android:mapkit:3.0.0'
2. Синхронизирую проект.
3. Пытаюсь запустить на физическом девайсе.

Как побороть?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос Ваши действия, которые привели к появлению данной ошибки. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это известная проблема в компиляторе D8, но исправление еще не вышло в новых релизах Android Studio.
https://github.com/yandex/mapkit-android-demo/issues/2
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77240639

Workaroud:
- Установить Android Studio 3.0.
- выключить D8. Добавить в gradle properties запись android.enableD8=false.